# Instagram API Approval

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

My application is currently in legacy mode. (Active until June 2016) If I apply for Instagram API Approval, and it's denied, will my application still function until June 2016, or will it be disabled?

Answer (score 1):

It will function, but it will be in sandbox mode. Only people listed as admins for the app will be able to use it.